# Not fetching contact-clicking contact it shows application has stopped

Tags: java, android, sms

I am using smsfunction to send an sms,i want to fetch contact list from my number,if i click edittext of phoneno it has to open contact list of my phone,and it has to fetch contact number whatever i am selecting and it has to send.

Right now in emulator,it shows "SMS faild, please try again later!" if i use that in device,after clicking any contact,it show "Myapplication has stopped"

Sendsmsactivity.java

```
public class SendSMSActivity extends Activity {
    public static final int RQS_PICKCONTACT    = 1; 
    Button buttonSend;
    //EditText textPhoneNo;
    EditText phoneNo;
    EditText textSMS;
    int columnIndex_number;
    static String stringNumber;
    String sms;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);

        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

        textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);
        /*textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
        textPhoneNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

                    //Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + textPhoneNo);
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
            }
    });*/

        phoneNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);

        phoneNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Uri uriContact = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
            Intent intentPickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uriContact);
            startActivityForResult(intentPickContact, RQS_PICKCONTACT);
        }
        });



        /*Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null) {
            String sms = extras.getString("firstKeyName");
        }*/


        Intent intent1= getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
        final String firstKeyName = intent1.getStringExtra("firstKeyName");


        textSMS.setText(firstKeyName);


        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              //String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();




              try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                //String name = null;

                smsManager.sendTextMessage(stringNumber, null, firstKeyName, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
              finish();

            }
        });
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

            switch (reqCode) {
                    case (PICK_CONTACT):
                            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                                //Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + textPhoneNo);
                                //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                                    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                                           final String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
                                            textPhoneNo.setText(name);
                                    }
                            }
                            break;
            }
    }*/


     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                if(requestCode == RQS_PICKCONTACT)
                {
                    Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
                    if(cursor.moveToNext()){
                        int columnIndex_ID = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
                        String contactID = cursor.getString(columnIndex_ID);

                        int columnIndex_HASPHONENUMBER = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
                        final String stringHasPhoneNumber = cursor.getString(columnIndex_HASPHONENUMBER);

                        if(stringHasPhoneNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                            Cursor cursorNum = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactID,null,null);

                            //Get the first phone number

                            if(cursorNum.moveToNext())
                            {
                                columnIndex_number = cursorNum.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                                 final String stringNumber = cursorNum.getString(columnIndex_number);
                                phoneNo.setText(stringNumber);
                            }
                        }else{
                            phoneNo.setText("NO Phone Number");
                         }

                    }else{
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


}
```

Its not fetching contact from myphone,is it having any error in my code.

```
Logcat error

06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://contacts }
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at com.example.jsonandroid.SendSMSActivity$1.onClick(SendSMSActivity.java:41)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-07 10:32:03.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i guess you will have to get the contacts and display it in a list with check boxes. choose the contacts by check boxes and send sms to those contacts. or open the contact list get the selected item and use the same to send sms

Comment: its going to contact page,if i click the contact,it show my application has stopped@Raghunandan

Comment: can you post your logcat? also check this http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Comment: also dude there is no logcat problem in my coding,in device only it shows application has stopped,if i use in emulator it shows sms failed

Comment: its a crash probably post your logcat details of the crash. you will know on which crash occurred. logcat has nothing do with your coding.

Comment: it showing the else part dude  "SMS faild, please try again later!",  @Raghunandan

Comment: @Raghunandan,can you tell how to do dude

Comment: @Raghunandan,what to do dude,to solve or find out the correct issue

Comment: you can use the below for reference.

Comment: @Raghunandan,can you come and give the result of selecting multiple contacts

Comment: why are in such a hurry wait. i post the solution

Comment: ya dude i will wait for your solution,very eagerly @Raghunandan

Comment: @Raghunandan, HAVE YOU  seen that question i posted there

Comment: @Raghunandan  Dude i have one doubt,i dont wants to show first main activity,i want to show first the sendsmsactivity only,if we click the edit textbox or new one button we will give,if we click that one,it has to show the contact list with checkbox after selecting the checkboxes it has to show their contact numbers in the edit text of phone number@Raghunandan,can you tell me how to do in that one.give some tips how to do from in this code itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below for reference and modify the same. i tested it on my phone works. Please post the logcat details of the crash wihtout which we can only guess the error.

you are calling finish() inside a button click which will finish the activity. Not sure what you are trying to do.

MainActivity.java

```
public class SendSmsActivity extends Activity {
Button buttonSend,get;
private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
EditText phoneNo;
EditText textSMS;
int columnIndex_number;
static String stringNumber;
String sms;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.send);
    phoneNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    get = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    get.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);


        }
        });
    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);    
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
          try {

              String sms =  textSMS.getText().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phoneNo.getText().toString()+sms,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo.getText().toString(), null, sms, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
          }


        }
    });
}

 @Override  
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
    switch (requestCode) {  
    case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:

        Cursor cursor = null;  
        String phoneNumber = "";
        List<String> allNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        int phoneIdx = 0;
        try {  
            Uri result = data.getData();  
            String id = result.getLastPathSegment();  
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);  
            phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                    allNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
                    phoneNo.setText(cursor.getString(phoneIdx));

                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            } else {
                //no results actions
            }  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
           //error actions
        } finally {  
            if (cursor != null) {  
                cursor.close();
            } 
        }  
        break;  
    }  
} else {
   //activity result error actions
}  
}
}
```

send.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Phone No"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
   </EditText>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="SMS Content"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:padding="20dp" />
    <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:paddingTop="20dp"
    >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:text="Get" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Send" />

 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

add the permissions in manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Snapshot from emulator. If you need to send sms you will have to use real device

If the number had spaces in between you can trim the space

[image]

Comment: dude,if i click get button application has stopped

Comment: pls post the logcat details of the crash else we can't help you further. for me the above works. i tested it on a device.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html. check the links

Comment: dude i mention my logcat error also,after clicking the get button,my application has stopped

Comment: in my question,can you look at i mention that logcat error what i am getting after clicking the get button

Comment: does your emulator have contacts? also if the application stopped its probably a crash and the crash report is logged in the logcat. so check the logcat or post the details of the crash here. Otherwise how can we know where the crash appears

Comment: Ya dude its working,thanks but we cant select more contacts from our contact list,why?Like if you want to send ten sms ,we will select checkbox in our contact list and it goes to that ten people.Right now only we are able to send only one person from contact list

Comment: pls ask a new question. that's a different question. if the answer helps pls accept the same. For that you need to get a list of contacts and then send sms

Comment: How to get list of contacts its selecting only one contact

Comment: pls post a new question with relevant details if not i someone will help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982674/how-to-select-more-contacts-from-my-contact-list-to-send-an-sms

Comment: dude thats my next question link,can you check it that one