# How to select more contacts from my contact list to send an sms

Tags: java, android, sms

Right now i am able to select only one contact from my contacts in my phone,i want to send sms more person in my contact list ,how can i send.

Right now i cant add more contacts in the phone no edit text even in manually also and getting from contact list also.

I want to send more contact number in my contact list to send an sms.what can i do

```
public class SendSMSActivity extends Activity {
Button buttonSend,get;
private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
EditText phoneNo;
EditText textSMS;
int columnIndex_number;
static String stringNumber;
String sms;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
    phoneNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    get = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    get.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);


        }
        });

    Intent intent1= getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
    final String firstKeyName = intent1.getStringExtra("firstKeyName");


    textSMS.setText(firstKeyName);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);    
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
          try {

              String sms =  textSMS.getText().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phoneNo.getText().toString()+firstKeyName,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo.getText().toString(), null, firstKeyName, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          finish();


        }
    });
}

 @Override  
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
    switch (requestCode) {  
    case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:

        Cursor cursor = null;  
        String phoneNumber = "";
        List<String> allNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        int phoneIdx = 0;
        try {  
            Uri result = data.getData();  
            String id = result.getLastPathSegment();  
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);  
            phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                    allNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
                    phoneNo.setText(cursor.getString(phoneIdx));

                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            } else {
                //no results actions
            }  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
           //error actions
        } finally {  
            if (cursor != null) {  
                cursor.close();
            } 
        }  
        break;  
    }  
} else {
   //activity result error actions
}  
}
}
```

Logcaterror its showing:

```
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.jsonandroid/com.example.jsonandroid.ContactActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at com.example.jsonandroid.SendSMSActivity$1.onClick(SendSMSActivity.java:42)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-07 14:06:05.546: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: hey i can edit the code i posted. the link you posted in the comment uses a built in sms facility.

Comment: have you edit your answer code dude?whats the mean or differentation of built in sms facility and ordinary we are using sms @Raghunandan

Comment: i suggest you go through the docs. i can't explain everything in detail. the get.xml is the same. i have made few minor changes. Modify according to your requirements. If you have doubts ask a new question i can't explain everything in comment

Comment: ok dude,where are the codes you changed,.bcz now i am using your code only@Raghunandan,can you tell me where you changed

Comment: see the edit section in the post. have doubts ask a new question. stop commenting so much

Comment: @Raghunandan,thank you dude i will look at it

Comment: @Raghunandan, you are not declaring row and checkbox    vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);  and  cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

Comment: what is the meaning of "declaring row and checkbox"?m You don't declare you initialize views. you can see the method inflate. your inflating a layout

Comment: @Raghunandan, You are not mention or declare that layout funcion  of row and even checkbox also dude,its showing error,remaining i changes whatever for me.

Comment: @Raghunandan, it showing error in two lines vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);  and  cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); in your Mainactivity,it shows error like this checkBox1,row cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: check the edit again.i forgot to post the layout to be inflated. you don't declare you inflate a layout. or you initialize them.

Comment: @Raghunandan can you post that layout also dude,if you dont mind,i clear all the thing what i need,i make all changes also,but dont know dude this one

Comment: check the last par of the post. should i keep asking you to look at the edited post?

Comment: @Raghunandan i am waiting for your answer or edit the post dude to solve that error,after its working i want to accept your answer here also,i am eager to do that one

Comment: @Raghunandan it shows lotcat error,as i mention above this line it shows   startActivityForResult(i, ResultCode);

Comment: dude i can't solve your problem all i can do is post the code snippets that's going to help you. You need to get your basics right. post a new question with logcat details. Others will help you

Comment: @Raghunandan dude this is the only one error,if its done i will go to my home,i am waiting for this error solving only,dude could you tell me whats the error

Comment: check your manifest file have you declared the activity. check the edit again. This all i can do. It seems you have not declared the activity in your manifest file. These are the basic things that you should learn. Next time nobody is going to spoon feed you which i probably did. Again if you have doubts pls pls post a new question

Comment: @Raghunandan, tnx dude i will check it and ping u,right now i am moving to my home,this is my gtalk id karthickbe2008@gmail.com,you send an blank sms,i will check and send the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all contacts  from the contact list and display it in a list. You can select the contacts using check box and click the button. Navigate to SendMessage activity and type the sms content and send message

I think there is a better way of dealing with checkboxes. For check box get selected item i followed the below link.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/No0LrgJ6q2M

Also you can fetch columns that you only need. Below fetches all columns which is not good.

```
  Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
```

get.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
   android:id="@+id/lv"/>
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
     android:text="Send" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

```
ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> phno0 = new ArrayList<String>();
MyAdapter ma ;
Button show,add;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.get);
    getAllCallLogs(this.getContentResolver());
    ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
     ma = new MyAdapter();
    lv.setAdapter(ma);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
    lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    // adding
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println(".............."+ma.mCheckStates.size());
            for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

                {
                if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                {
                      phno0.add(phno1.get(i).toString()) ;
                     checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                     checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                }
                else
                {
           System.out.println("..Not Checked......"+name1.get(i).toString());
                }


            }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, checkedcontacts,1000).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SendMessage.class));
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("name",phno0);
                startActivity(intent); 

        }       
    });


}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ma.toggle(arg2);
}

public  void getAllCallLogs(ContentResolver cr) {

    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
      String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
      String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
      System.out.println(".................."+phoneNumber); 
      name1.add(name);
      phno1.add(phoneNumber);
    }

    phones.close();
 }
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
{  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
   LayoutInflater mInflater;
    TextView tv1,tv;
    CheckBox cb;
    MyAdapter()
    {
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
         vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); 
         TextView tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
         tv.setText("Name :"+ name1.get(position));
         tv1.setText("Phone No :"+ phno1.get(position));
         cb.setTag(position);
         cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
         cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return vi;
    }
     public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);                 
    }       
}   
}
```

SendMessage.java

```
   public class SendMessage extends Activity {

EditText ed1,ed2;
ArrayList<String> sendlist = new ArrayList<String>();
Button b1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sendmessage);
    ed1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        sendlist = extras.getStringArrayList("name");
        if(sendlist!=null)
        {
        for(int i=0;i<sendlist.size();i++)
        {
            ed1.append(sendlist.get(i).toString());
            ed1.append(";");
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "null",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i=0;i<sendlist.size();i++)
            {

                if(ed2.getText().length()>0)
                {
                  try {
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(sendlist.get(i).toString(), null, ed2.getText().toString(), null, null);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                }
            }

        }

    });
}   
}
```

sendmessage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Phone Numbers" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:text="Message" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to add these two permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Edit:

Open SendMessage Activity first. Click the get button next to editext1. Navigate to MainActivity which displays all contacts and select using check boxes. Click send will finish the actiivty and retunn sms activity. You can see the selected contacts in editext 1. The rest is the same.

I have used startActivity for result. This more than i can do to help you. pls modify the same accordingly.

```
  public class SendMessage extends Activity {

EditText ed1,ed2;
static int ResultCode= 12;
ArrayList<String> sendlist = new ArrayList<String>();
Button b1,b2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sendmessage);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    ed1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(SendMessage.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ResultCode);
    }

 });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i=0;i<sendlist.size();i++)
            {

                if(ed2.getText().length()>0)
                {
                  try {
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(sendlist.get(i).toString(), null, ed2.getText().toString(), null, null);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                }
            }

        }

    });
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

      if (requestCode == ResultCode) {

         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
             sendlist  =data.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
             if(sendlist!=null)
                {
                for(int i=0;i<sendlist.size();i++)
                {
                    ed1.append(sendlist.get(i).toString());
                    ed1.append(";");
                }

         }
         if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    

         }
      }
    }
}
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Phone Numbers" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:text="Message" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Send" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Get" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{


ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> phno0 = new ArrayList<String>();
MyAdapter ma ;
Button send;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.get);
    getAllCallLogs(this.getContentResolver());
    ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
     ma = new MyAdapter();
    lv.setAdapter(ma);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
    lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println(".............."+ma.mCheckStates.size());
            for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

                {
                if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                {
                      phno0.add(phno1.get(i).toString()) ;
                     checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                     checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("..Not Checked......"+name1.get(i).toString());
                }


            }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, checkedcontacts,1000).show();
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                 returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name",phno0);
                 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
                 finish();

        }       
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ma.toggle(arg2);
}

public  void getAllCallLogs(ContentResolver cr) {

    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
      String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
      String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
      System.out.println(".................."+phoneNumber); 
      name1.add(name);
      phno1.add(phoneNumber);
    }

    phones.close();
 }
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
{  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
   LayoutInflater mInflater;
    TextView tv1,tv;
    CheckBox cb;
    MyAdapter()
    {
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
         vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); 
         tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
         tv.setText("Name :"+ name1.get(position));
         tv1.setText("Phone No :"+ phno1.get(position));
         cb.setTag(position);
         cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
         cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return vi;
    }
     public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);                 
    }       
}   
}
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="TextView" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />
 </RelativeLayout
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sendsmstoall"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.sendsmstoall.SendMessage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Dude for my code ,how can i add,having lots of confussion  how to do this thing in my code,where i have to add the first line in my code

Comment: I can't help you with that part you need to get that right. Start a new project and try the above. it works on my phone

Comment: ,i got some thing,i have to remove the sendsmsactivity from my code,and then i have to include your code, am i correct

Comment: you main activity is for getting the contacts from contact list and display the same. When you tick the checkboxes and click the button you will navigate to send message activity. you would see the numbers in a edittext. then you can type the sms content in the second edittext and click send button which will send the sms content to the list of selected contacts

Comment: ya dude,ok  i will try and ping you

Comment: Dude i have one doubt,i dont wants to show first main activity,i want to show first the sendsmsactivity only,if we click the edit textbox or new one button we will give,if we click that one,it has to show the contact list with checkbox after selecting the checkboxes it has to show their contact numbers in the edit text of phone number@Raghunandan,can you tell me how to do in that one.give some tips how to do from in this code itself

Comment: Hi dude, i have one thing in my editextbox of phone number there inside the onclicklistener ,i will give the contact list activity intent,after selecting the contacts,you gave an again an intent to come back again,and it will shows what are the contacts we selects it has to show in our exitbox of phonenumber.is it correct?????

Comment: i posted a solution it may not be exactly what you want. you need to  modify the above according to your requirements. If you have any doubts regarding the above code i can help otherwise i can't

Comment: Dude i have one example of code having only three lines code is there it will do all the things,it will shows contact list with checkbox also.                                                 Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", strContactList); 
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(sendIntent);@Raghunandan

Comment: i will try and post the solution. but you should be able to do it on your own. yup there might be a better solution as i already told you in the post earlier

Comment: ya dude,i will do,but only one thing is there dude,after sending the sms it not come back again if we use that code,what the problem in that one@Raghunandan

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/ can you see this link of second type model dude.can you look at that one

Comment: http://pastebin.com/e5Lj0hxZ can you see this my code,only three code,but is not come back again,eventhough i put finish button also dude,why its not come back again  dude@Ragahunandan, i put your answer is userful also dude

Comment: you are not giving that R.layout,.row at all and checkbox view also,how to do that one

Comment: Raghunandan, your solution is great but can you explain me one thing is there to make selects contacts views exactly like when we select contacts in default android select view througn sms.

Comment: @Mubeen1992 it is possible

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking something about if it is predefine in android like if I use this action
Intent contactpicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
startActivityForResult(contactpicker, 0);
I get that screen but I can only select one contact

Comment: Did you get my question?

Comment: @Mubeen1992 that is also possible with the contact picker. Google search or search on stackoverflow you will find many. depends on what contacts picker you have installed on your device

Comment: @Mubeen1992 you can pick only one contact at a time. You need to have a custom listview to pick  many contacts. That is possible

Comment: Thanks, and I was searching for contacts picker but no relevant answer

Comment: Right now I am getting contacts order by `Phone No` can i get order by `Name`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59941/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-mubeen1992).

Comment: @Mubeen1992 if you need more help i made a sample which i could post if you ask a question

Comment: @Raghunandan If I will feel need I will ask you Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Raghunandan can you tell me how can use group by in this query?